# Geolocalização em html

Tags: android, html5

No meu aplicativo tenho uma webview, e la tem o link de endereço, queria que aparecesse o bonequinho informando a localização.Como chamo em html?

Comment: é um aplicativo android, sendo que essa tela é uma webview, ou seja uma pagina html, quero que apareça a localização ao clicar, sendo que aquela com o bonequinho informando onde está.

Comment: Esse `WebView` tem um mapa e nele você quer obter e apontar a localização do usuário, é isso?

Comment: isso, a localização eu ja tenho, latitude e longitude, como faço para ficar da forma correta no mapa?

Comment: Tente colocar a url da webview com coordenadas, exemplo: `google.com/maps/?q=-15.623037,18.388672`

Comment: o lugar atual ou um local que seja exibido?

Comment: Rafael, funcionou obrigado, transforma em resposta valeu

Comment: @WarLock, pronto :)

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema se resolve na URL.

Coloque a URL da `WebView` com coordenadas, por exemplo:

```
google.com/maps/?q=-15.623037,18.388672
```